# Prove that for any positive integer n the following identity holds,

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

[image]

am i supposed to use mathematical induction to prove this?

If i do, i have no idea how to start the proof.

any tips or suggestions would be great!

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried to figure out how to make it work out for some small $n$?

Comment: yes I put n=1 and i don't see much progress..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Add $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ to both sides, and check that you get the same result.

When you are adding on the right, note that you are adding two copies of $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+\frac{1}{2n}$.

**Remark:** One can also do an induction proof. When we increment $n$ by $1$, the left-hand side increases by an amount $\frac{1}{2n+1}+\frac{1}{2n+2}-\frac{1}{n+1}$. and the right-hand side increases by an amount $\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}$. These two quantities are easily verified to be equal.

Comment: what do you mean "adding two copies of 1/2 + 1/4 ... + 1/2n"??

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots=2\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Another hint. Add to the negative entries on the right. If you prefer, I have added a large hint on how to do the proof by induction instead. For the first way, take a small example, like $n=3$, to see what's going on. The $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}$ that you add will cancel the negatives and turn them into positives of the same absolute value. Work on this. If you tell me tomorrow (Pacific time) that you still have trouble, I will write out one or two complete solutions

Answer (score 1):

Since the following 2 expressions
$$\begin{align}
\text{LHS}_{n+1} - \text{LHS}_{n} = & \frac{1}{2n+2} + \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{n+1}\\
\text{RHS}_{n+1} - \text{RHS}_{n} = & \frac{1}{2n+1} - \frac{1}{2n+2}
\end{align}$$
clearly equal to each other, we have

$$\text{LHS}_{n+1} - \text{RHS}_{n+1} = \text{LHS}_{n} - \text{RHS}_{n}$$

Since $\text{LHS}_1 = \frac{1}{1+1} = 1 - \frac{1}{2} = \text{RHS}_1$, we have $\text{LHS}_n = \text{RHS}_n$ for all $n$.

Comment: that's brilliant. thanks for letting me know this method. I'll remember for a long time! but just one question: how do you know if LHS1 = 1/(1+1)???

Comment: @Dafty Just plug in the definition. For general $n$, the LHS start summing $\frac{1}{k}$ at $k = n+1$ and end the sum at $k = 2n$. When $n = 1$, this reduces to start and end the sum at the same spot $k = 2$.